# Hosting a web from my PC (Using IIS7)

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, web-hosting, web-deployment

I was wondering why not host the application from my office itself? I have a static IP. What else do I need to make my local server accessible on the Internet? I know I need a domain name but I am new to hosting so I don't know how to go about it. How will I link my static WAN IP to the domain. Right now when I type my WAN IP on the net , my ISP shows up a site blocked page. I don't know what to do.
It is an ASP.net web app.

Comment: It's strange that you can't access your website by entering its IP address - this should work fine. Maybe your ISP doesn't allow incoming http connections to your office? They may do this to protect against hacking attempts. You should contact them to see if this is the case. It's fine hosting websites from your office. My company does this - we only have old hardware so we don't host public-facing websites, but use it for hosting internal software and demo websites for clients.

Comment: keep in mind that your PC is probably not a server, you restart it sometimes, can crash or be non responsive... hosted ASP.NET application would have way better/higher availability and reliability levels.

Comment: Could be DNS, Firewall, NAT, etc. You'll have better luck on serverfault.com, where the network experts hangout.

Comment: For the reasons outlined in the answers by Icarus and Frazell Thomas This is a really bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, are your sure the IP address you have at your office is a static public ip address? [You may have an internal IP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network). What I mean is that YOUR Computer may have an internal IP address so yo would need to configure your router to forward connections to port 80 to your specific IP address inside your LAN.

You can register your domain at any registrar of your choice (I am hesitant to mention one). You should have an option to link your domain name to your IP address somewhere at the registrar's site. After you do this, you should be able to go http://yourdomainjustregistered.com and hit your IIS Server.

My understanding is that versions of IIS that are shipped with regular home computers have restrictions on how many connections can be made concurrently. You would need to get a Server version of Windows.

If your ISP shows a site blocked page when you type your ip address, it may be the case that they block port 80 to their customers so that they don't run personal websites without paying them a fee. You need to find out what's their policy regarding this, drop them if they do something like this and find another ISP. Alternatively, you can run your web server on a different port (8180, for example) and use all kinds of techniques to redirect users that hit http://yourdomain.com to this port on your box. You would need to adjust IIS to listen on this port too.

Comment: correct. Windows Client is limited to 10 simultaneous connections. IIS 7 on Windows 7 will queue up connections in excess of 10 (instead of throwing a hard error).

Comment: Thanks for the response Icarus. It is not an Internal IP but it is a WAN IP as it shows on my router's status page. I will check about the port forwarding issue. And I will install a server version of windows(2008). Yes, my ISP did blocked the port 80 request to my WAN IP for money matter. I will discuss it with my ISP and then get back to you in case I have further doubts.

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of things that need to fall in place before the web application will be accessible from the Internet.

1. You need to open the relevant ports on your router/firewall (Port 80/443 for web apps).
2. If you are in a NAT situation you need to forward the ports to the right machine.
3. The machine also needs to have its firewall set to open the ports.

The above steps will allow the page to load via the IP address only. To load the page with a domain name you need to adjust your site's DNS server to recognize the IP address for that domain name.

All of this is very broad because without knowing your exact configuration detailed answers can't be given.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Frazell. I will try this also and at least test my application before buying a domain name. I have an ASP .net web application that uses Crystal reports 10, MS SQL server 2008 R2 database currently deployed at somee.com(for free) but will put that on the same computer too, MS .Net framework 3.5 all running at 64 bit machine. I am thinking to format the computer and reinstall only required applications and then deploy the app. I will let you know if I succeed. Thanks a lot.